# OutOfMemory Exception from Struts Ajax call when using non-primitive Java objects

Tags: ajax, jquery, struts2, enums

I've got a relatively simple Ajax call to a Struts 2.2.3.1 action that returns a simple Java POJO. Once we add a simple Enum to that POJO and execute the action, we get a bunch of messages like this in our server's logs:

```
[10/19/12 14:55:07:124 EDT] 00000047 BeanAdapter   I com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info Class com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.jitdeploy.JIT_StubPluginImpl has no readable properties,  trying to adapt JIT_StubClassPlugin with StringAdapter...
[10/19/12 14:55:07:124 EDT] 00000047 BeanAdapter   I com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info Class com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.jitdeploy.JIT_StubPluginImpl has no readable properties,  trying to adapt JIT_StubClassPlugin with StringAdapter...
[10/19/12 14:55:07:139 EDT] 00000047 BeanAdapter   I com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info Class com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.jitdeploy.JIT_StubPluginImpl has no readable properties,  trying to adapt JIT_StubClassPlugin with StringAdapter...
[10/19/12 14:55:07:139 EDT] 00000047 BeanAdapter   I com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info Class com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.jitdeploy.JIT_StubPluginImpl has no readable properties,  trying to adapt JIT_StubClassPlugin with StringAdapter...
```

And then finally see an OutOfMemory Exception.

Out Struts XML for the Ajax call is similar to:

```
    <action name="ajaxRetrieveThing" class="x.y.z.action.Thing" method="ajaxRetrieveThing">
        <result type="xslt">
            <param name="exposedValue">actionResponse</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

The relavant portions of our ActionResponse class are:

```
public class ActionResponse {
    // a bunch of primitive types and associated getters and setters skipped

    private List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public List<?> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void addResult(Object o) {
        results.add(o);
    }
    public void setResultList(List results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

In our action, we put a Thing in the list of Results. Where Thing is a POJO with primitive fields and our ThingEnum in it.

Our Enum looks like this:

```
public enum ThingEnum {
    VALUE_1( "1" ), VALUE_2( "2" ); // etc

    String description;
    private ThingEnum( String description ) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }   
}
```

The action will work and we can get data to our JavaScript until we add the ThingEnum in. I assume this is because Struts runs into a problem when it tries to convert the ThingEnum to XML. We've had problems similar to this with other types of objects (Hibernate entities, for example) and got around them by just storing the Strings and other primitives we need in the result objects.

What's the correct way to work around this issue? I'd like to avoid having to manually convert the Enum to a String before passing back to JS which is our current solution - instead of having a ThingEnum field, we basically have a thingDescription String in our Result object.

Comment: What's with the adapter trying to convert that JIT EJB class?  That doesn't sound like a pojo.  Where is it getting that class from?

Comment: @rees, Hmm. I'm not sure where that's coming from. Is it possible it's part of Java's enum implementation?